# Bootstrap checkbox to appear before submit button on small screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have tried to find a solution for this, but haven't been able to.

I have a setup where three input fields and a submit buttton are shown next to each other on large screens, but they're wrapped in `<div class="col-sm">` in order to stack vertically on mobile. However, I need to have a checkbox shown before the submit button on small screens, but on the large screen it's fine to have it shown underneath the input fields.

```
            <form method="post">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="required email form-control form-rounded" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded" placeholder="Number">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input name="comp" id="comp" type="text" class="form-control form-rounded" placeholder="Company">
                </div>                  
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="subscribesubmit" class="button btn-block" value="Sign up">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="contactconsent" class="d-flex justify-content-center margin-top-small">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="consent" id="contactconsentcheck">
                  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="contactconsentcheck">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                  </label>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I was onto something about manipulating the margins in a mediaquery, but it feels like a bad solution. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: We need to have the setup, to reproduce what you have so we can help you.

Comment: According to your description you should have a look at a grid system. It's independant from the HTML structure and the HTML structure can be written semantically and does not need to be changed. But solving it with mediaqueries isn't a bad solution. Just avoid manipulation the HTML syntax with JS.

Comment: As mentioned above by @ZimSystem you need to include the code so that your problem can be reproduced. Here is a link to a guide on how to express a problem [mcve]. Hope it helps!

Comment: i think you are looking for order https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order

Comment: Added the code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Be sure to click the "Full Page" button and you click "Run code snippet" so that you can resize the demo window.

```css
.my-form {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
}

.text-fields {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 22px;
}

.submit-btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .my-form {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .text-fields {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .submit-btn {
      margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="my-form">
  <div class="inputs">
    <div class="text-fields">
      <input class="text" type="text">
      <input class="text" type="text">
      <input class="text" type="text">
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works really well in your example, but I can't get it to work properly. Maybe I need to play around with it a bit more.

Comment: Going with this method, you would probably be best served to avoid using any of the Bootstrap column classes.